# How do I get the ARN of an AWS Lambda function for a Cloud Formation specific resource property?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

I can't seem to get `Ref` or `Fn:GetAtt` to return a valid value for use with setting up a resource.

*serverless.yml*

```
...etc...

functions:
  bearerTokenAuthentication:
    handler: app.bearerTokenAuthentication
    name: ${self:service}-auth-bearer

resources:
  - ${file(./serverless_resources.yml)}
```

*serverless_resources.yml*

```
Resources:
  ApiGateway:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
    Properties:
        Name: restapi-${self:provider.stage}
        Description: Endpoints
        ApiKeySourceType: HEADER # (to read the API key from the X-API-Key header of a request)

  ApiGatewayBearerAuthorizer:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Authorizer
    Properties:
      Type: token
      IdentitySource: method.request.header.Authorization
      Name: BearerAuthorization
      AuthorizerResultTtlInSeconds: 300
      AuthorizerUri: !Join  #arn:aws:apigateway:${self:provider.region}:lambda:path/${self:functions.bearerTokenAuthentication.name}
        - ''
        - - 'arn:aws:apigateway:'
          - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
          - ':lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/'
          - !GetAtt 
            - bearerTokenAuthentication # also tried !Ref bearerTokenAuthentication and '${self:functions.bearerTokenAuthentication.name}'
            - Arn
          - /invocations
      RestApiId: !Ref ApiGateway
```

No matter what I do, `GetAtt` cannot find the ARN for the Lambda function declared in `bearerTokenAuthentication`.  I just keep getting this error:

> Error: The CloudFormation template is invalid: Template error: instance of Fn::GetAtt references undefined resource bearerTokenAuthentication

... or if trying `Ref` ...

> Error: The CloudFormation template is invalid: Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [bearerTokenAuthentication] in the Resources block of the template

Is it possible to reference Lambda ARNs from the resource section? It seems by the error messages it is looking for "resource" names.  I always thought the lambda function declaration was also considered a resource (besides the obvious `Resources:` block of course), perhaps I am misunderstanding something.

Comment: If its the “Unresolved resource dependency” issue, you can add “DependsOn: bearerTokenAuthentication” between the Type and Properties attributes of “ApiGatewayBearerAuthorizer” which will prevent creation of that resource until bearerTokenAuthentication is created and available.

Comment: Doesn't do anything.  Seems to ignore it completely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out. I had a NodeJS project and was using the "serverless" command line (sls) to deploy using `serverless.yml`.  It turns out it creates a `.serverless` sub-directroy with some files in it.  One of them is a compiled template for AWS Cloud Formation called `cloudformation-template-update-stack.json`. It appears that the utility likes to mangle the names by making the first character uppercase and adding "LambdaFunction" to all the function names (for whatever reason).  In this case, `bearerTokenAuthentication` was renamed to `BearerTokenAuthenticationLambdaFunction` (the actual resource name).  After looking into the compiled template it all became clear.  The utility also seems to figure out the dependencies as well, which was good to know. This was the final result:

```
  AuthorizerUri: !Join 
    - ''
    - - 'arn:aws:apigateway:'
      - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
      - ':lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/'
      - !GetAtt [ BearerTokenAuthenticationLambdaFunction, Arn ]
      - '/invocations'
```

**Other "Gotchas":**

DO NOT define the `AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi` resource (like I did in my question) if you are also using `event` mappings with the functions, otherwise you will get 2 APIs created. `event` entries automatically cause an API to be created called "ApiGatewayRestApi" - which is the resource name generated by the `sls` utility. The last line of the last file was changed to this:

```
  RestApiId: !Ref ApiGatewayRestApi
```

And my `ApiGateway:` section was removed.

Credit goes to this post which helped make it more clear to me what was really going on: https://forum.serverless.com/t/fixed-how-do-i-get-reference-api-gateway-restapi-id-in-serverless-yml/3397/5

**Previous Answer:**

I found another way as well. This is what I resorted to doing until I found the proper (shorter) way. I was able to pull the lambda name and manually stitch together the required URI:

```
  AuthorizerUri: !Join
    - ''
    - - 'arn:aws:apigateway:'
      - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
      - ':lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:'
      - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
      - ':'
      - !Ref 'AWS::AccountId'
      - ':function:'
      - '${self:functions.bearerTokenAuthentication.name}'
      - '/invocations'
```

I hope that helps save someone some time trying to understand the complicated .yml file.  I also cannot understand why it is so hard to make it simple to understand.  All someone had to do is say (for me) was "sls takes a 'serverless.yml' file, and optional include files (such as declarations specific to the cloud system itself, like AWS Cloud Formation), and generates a template JSON file that is used by the target cloud services system to deploy your solution. Also, the names you give may get mangled, so check the template." I'm also surprised that no one has created an editor to make all this easier by now - perhaps something I'll look into myself one day. ;)

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thanks very much for sharing this!

Comment: Thanks! You made my day.

Answer (score 1):

You can always go to the deployed lambda and look for the aws:cloudformation:logical-id tag. That way you get the logical ID you should be using in your serverless.yaml. (Don't like this behind-the-scenes names tricks either...)